# VBA Encryption Method

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a very simple Ceaser Cipher encryption algorithm on VBA. It takes a string value and applies *x* shift.

Quite happy with it. However, would like to take it to the next step, but I am not sure if it is doable.

I would like to call this encryption function in another module and pass a string value to encrypt.

I.e. What I am trying to do is something like this

```
Private Sub Encryption()
   'Encryption method of string Var
End Sub
```

---- and in another sub ----

```
Private Sub function()
   Dim Text as String
   Text = "Hello"
   Encryption(Text)
End Sub
```

So in this example, I have defined a method to encrypt any string variable. In the other function, I defined a string and initialised it as "Hello". Then called Encryption function on it... Not sure if this is doable in VBA?

I am not sure how I could pass in a variable when I am calling a function within a function. Any advise please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to change the [Sub Routine to a Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures). Also, get rid of the `Private` keyword as this will not allow you to call it across different modules.

So Change this:

```
Private Sub Encryption()
   'Encryption method of string Var
End Sub
```

to this:

```
Function Encryption(ByVal inputString as String) As String
   'Encryption method of string Var
End Sub
```

---

Now, inside your function you need to change whatever variable holds the first string (the one to be encrypted) to the newly created variable, `inputString`. It's hard to help you in this area as you did not provide the full code for `Sub Encryption()`.

Also, ensure that you set the **Function** name itself to the newly encrypted text within the function. So your function would essentially look as follows:

```
Function Encryption(ByVal inputString as String) As String
   'Encryption method of string Var
    Encryption = 'the value to return from this function        
End Sub
```

---

Now, your second sub would look like this:

```
Private Sub test()
   Dim Text as String, encryptedText as String
   Text = "Hello"
   encryptedText = Encryption(Text)
End Sub
```

You will just make the new variable `encryptedText` equal to the new function, `Encryption`.

---

So, the major difference between a `Sub` and a `Function` is that a Function will *return values*. They both essentially process code the same way.

### METHOD 2 (Edit)

After rethinking your question, I believe that you were using your Sub to obtain your encrypted text from passing the variable as `ByRef`, and you may just be having difficulties with calling the Sub because of the `Private` keyword.

If this what was going on, then you can simply remove the Private keyword and it should work as intended.

So your Sub should look like:

```
Sub Encryption()    '<-- Notice, no Private scope
   'Encryption method of string Var
End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub Encryption()
   'Encryption method of string Var
End Sub
```

You should take a [look at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope) for additional reading regarding scope.

Comment: It's not really clear what the OP is after, but I'd say you did a pretty good job of _deciphering_ the meaning..  Nice job